# C#: Different string encoding on attribute vs. constant

Tags: c#, string, unicode, encoding

I'm writing a test for a function aimed to remove invalid code points such as orphaned surrogate pairs.
However, I'm seeing a difference in the way the surrogate pair is being encoded depending on how I write the test.

While this version of the test passes:

```
        [TestCategory("UnitTest")]
        [TestMethod]
        public void RemoveOrhpanedSurrogatePair()
        {
            var input = "\uDDDD1975";
            var cleanText = input.ReplaceInvalidCodePoints();

            Assert.AreEqual(input.Length - 1, cleanText.Length);
            Assert.AreEqual("1975", cleanText);
        }
```

This one does not:

```cs
        [TestCategory("UnitTest")]
        [TestMethod]
        [DataRow("\uDDDD1975")]
        public void RemoveOrhpanedSurrogatePair(string input)
        {
            var cleanText = input.ReplaceInvalidCodePoints();

            Assert.AreEqual(input.Length - 1, cleanText.Length);
            Assert.AreEqual("1975", cleanText);
        }
```

Looking at the debugger, the first variation encoded the string as `"\uDDDD1975"` but the second one produces `"��1975"` which appears as two valid characters instead of one orphaned surrogate pair.

Comment: Can reproduce the same behavior with any attribute https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aux1H7

Comment: Also seems to be compiled like this https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0ASgKYBmANsQMYAuAlgPYB2A3OnAMy4LYDC2Ab3QBITtz4BXAM40GAWwCCNGgCc6wCTWLYQ2JavWbiIoWmGiuvabMXK1GrQAo8OLTICUI4afPCAKsQy2AC82G40bGbmeACcjuHukeYAvuheYi7YATJePuYA5sQRXsJSRUnCqWZVIgDaVjLyjgBEADoSACJdHUgxAOwArM3uALoiGUg42fRM+SZehcVRZUuVaWaICPNRAG4AhirYdEwADpoh2G2d3b2DzRX7hycqDCfEKjQAnhdfbwykjl47nwAHEigAFF5vD6fFrTY75YYPA7YPZ2QxaC7PV7vL6gooNGz6exGAA8hPkxIxxAAfI5Euleo5jmcaAzquhkkA===

Comment: I am guessing this is a Roslyn issue

Comment: A string is an array of unicode characters. When the input isn't  valid characters, anything can happen.

Comment: ECMA-335 CLI spec says in I.24.2.4 that any reachable part of a `#Userstring` blob should contain only valid UTF16. This is for normal strings. So this would not be verifiable. Whereas for custom attributes in I.23.3 it only needs a string of code points.

Comment: ECMA-334 C# spec, interestingly, does not define in 7.4.5.6 whether a string literal must be normalized. But obviously, that would depend on the CLI. But in 22.4.2 it specifically calls out non-normalized strings as implementation-defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a clue to the answer can be found in (what else but) a @jonskeet [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/11/07/when-is-a-string-not-a-string/). Apparently C# uses UTF16 to encode strings everywhere, *except* in Attribute c'tors where UTF8 is being used. The compiler seems to see that this is an orphaned surrogate pair and treats it via its UTF8 value as two invalid Unicode characters. Those are then being replaced by a pair of `\uFFFD` characters (the [Unicode replacement character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) which is used to indicate broken data when decoding binary to text).

```cs
[Description(Value)]
class Test
{
    const string Value = "\uDDDD";
 
    static void Main()
    {
        var description = (DescriptionAttribute)
            typeof(Test).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)[0];
        DumpString("Attribute", description.Description);
        DumpString("Constant", Value);
    }
 
    static void DumpString(string name, string text)
    {
        var utf16 = text.Select(c => ((uint) c).ToString("x4"));
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, string.Join(" ", utf16));
    }
}
```

Will produce:

```
Attribute: fffd fffd
Constant: dddd
```